# regX and regY change after I publish the Flash Pro file

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas, createjs

I created a movieclip in Flash Pro and placed it on the stage. When I created the movieclip I made sure the registrations point was set to the upper left side (0,0) I placed it on the stage and I set it's X and Y cords to 0.[image]

In the javascript window I wrote this code to check and then set the regX and regY to what I thought was the same position.

```
 var my_stage = this;
 console.log(my_stage.chnages.regX); -->(150)
 console.log(my_stage.chnages.regY); -->(125)

 my_stage.chnages.regX = 0;
 my_stage.chnages.regY = 0;
```

So even though on the stage it says the X and Y cords of the movieclip are 0,0, when I publish the file, it then reads as X:150, Y:125? And when I set the x and y cords to 0,0, it then centers the top left corner of my movieclip on the stage. 
[image]

Do I have to set the stage property to be 0,0 and have that be the top left of the stage? I'm coming from a flash workflow and never ran into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

CreateJS doesn't support a separate transform origin like Flash. The `regX` and `regY` are where the content will draw from, as well as the origin of transformation

If you have the image on the top left in Flash Pro and move the transformation point, it will counter-move the content so it draws as expected in the browser.

Comment: So why when I set the X and Y properties of the movieclip in flash pro to be x and y = 0, but then set the same movieclip with regX and regY = 0 in the javascript actions panel, they are 2 different points?

Answer (score 0):

Origin ( the small + sign inside movieclip) is not the regx and regy as you are thinking. 
When you publish from flash, the regx and regy is determined by the small "circular-dot" when you click the object to resize or rotate it. Move it to 0,0 or whatever x,y you want. The regx and regy will change to that values.